# Using "The" when starting sentence with a noun

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

My sentence starts with a noun:

Shall I add "The":

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) is becoming ..

or leave it without an article:

> HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) is becoming ..

Comment: I guess you should. It's important.

Comment: Generally speaking, there would be no article. But it depends on the context of the complete sentence and the surrounding text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether it's at the start of a sentence or not doesn't matter - the question is whether it's appropriate to use the definite article in this case. If you see this as a noun phrase where *protocol* is being modified by *hypertext transfer*, then you certainly need a determiner, and as there's just the one such protocol you would want *the*. However, you can also see *HyperText Transfer Protocol* as a proper noun.

Proper nouns sometimes use definite articles, and sometimes don't. Each of them develops their own convention. [Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hypertext%20transfer%20protocol%2Cthe%20hypertext%20transfer%20protocol&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chypertext%20transfer%20protocol%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20hypertext%20transfer%20protocol%3B%2Cc0) suggests that it is used with *the* sometimes, usually not, but enough that using *the* wouldn't be seen as incorrect.